# Sphinx executing sql_query_post_index query too early, before indexing is complete

Tags: sphinx

We have a main and delta index operating on one of our databases. The delta index always lives separate from the main index, i.e. it isn't merged into the main at any point. The delta index runs every five minutes and the main index is fully recalculated every four hours. It takes anywhere from half an hour to an hour to do the full re-index.

We're running into an issue where documents that are added to the database after the last full re-index will be added to the delta index, but then disappears when the next full re-index job starts. In the Sphinx configuration for our main index, we have the following lines:

```
sql_query_pre = UPDATE sphinx SET max_doc_id_temp = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM deal) WHERE alias = "merchant_deal_{{ language }}"
...
sql_query_post_index = UPDATE sphinx SET max_doc_id = max_doc_id_temp WHERE alias = "merchant_deal_{{ language }}"
```

In theory, this should set `max_doc_id_temp` to the ID of the most recently posted document at the time the full re-index job starts. Then, after the indexing is complete, we set `max_doc_id` to be the same value. The delta index job only runs on any documents with an ID higher than `max_doc_id`.

In practice, `max_doc_id` seems to change about 10-15 minutes into the full re-index job, which is well before the new index is completed and in place. This means any delta indices calculated past that point will be missing some documents, and they won't reappear in Sphinx searches until after the full re-index is done.

I thought `sql_query_post_index` was only supposed to run once "indexing is fully and successfully completed," according to the Sphinx documentation, but it appears this might not be the case. Is there some other way to get this to work? Maybe a different sphinx configuration parameter I can use instead, or some bug we're running into that's causing `sql_query_post_index` to run prematurely?

Comment: If you run indexer with --print-queries can you see that the _post_index query is issue while the indexation is still running? If you don't, but still think it happens can you see that in your mysql binary log?

Comment: Output from --print-queries seems to show the _post_index SQL running at the end of the output. When I try to inspect the binary logs, though, the SQL runs twice, at 8 minutes in and 16 minutes into the job. Also, the sql_query_pre query isn't present at all in the binary log. I'm new to reading binary logs so I might be missing something here.

Comment: Actually it looks like the `sql_query_post_index` is running as part of the delta index as well, which it absolutely shouldn't. I think this just became a sphinx configuration question, but I guess I should ask that separately.